# Why was my comment deleted?

Tags: discussion

I posted two comments in response  at [How can octogenarians pull out a refrigerator surrounded by walls?](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/q/23926), but I no longer see it. Why was it deleted?

Answer (score 2):

Your comments received flags as being unfriendly or unkind.

The system then automatically deleted them.

Answer (score 2):

Second and more general explanation:

[Comments are temporary by design.](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) Once they are outdated, no longer helpful or a question simply gathers too many, they can and likely will be removed. Never rely on a comment to be attached to a post forever.